# How may I stop Chromium browser to attempt resolving DNS on their own?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, chromium

> When I say *resolve DNS on their own* I'm not referring to DoH, thought by extension it's in there too.
> I mean regular/standard/unencrypted/"classic" DNS.

When I switch networks on my computer; e.g; from my habitual subnet that's heavily firewalled to one that's not; as soon as the change is detected, I get a popup from my in-host firewall stating Vivaldi/Chromium/Chrome/Brave/… wants to make new connections to `<ip-address-set-on-my-system's-settings>` on **UDP:53**, instead of letting the system handle that — that's how it's supposed to work, right? Apps on a host use the system's resolver; from layer7 to layer1, communications are passed down and vice versa.

If I say NO to the popup, the browser stops working altogether because it's set as a rule. Because I said NO, I assume the connection is **rejected** explicitly rather than just **dropped** which would be the case if I set up the firewall from *alert mode* to *silently block* everything, during which period rules aren't created for the traffic blocked.

During a silent block, a Chromium browser would keep working using the system's resolver. Or at least that the only plausible explanation I have for it, but the network activity of the system's DNS client process reported by the same firewall sort of confirms it.

I'm not a big Chromium user, only when I need to access a site without undoing security in Firefox, which is kind of a chore. But as I gather, like Firefox, it has this ***flags*** thing that are akin to Firefox's ***about:*** (e.g; about:about) pages. Could the setting be there perhaps? If so, how can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome prefers to use its own resolver for DNS, which lets it manage things like cache or DoH internally so that things like clearing chrome's cache doesn't affect the entire system. By default, it will read the system's DNS settings, but won't use the resolver unless it has to.

Currently, the only way to force chrome to use the system resolver for everything is with a command-line flag that takes a list of mappings like so, which should work for any chromium browser:

```
chrome.exe --host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE 127.0.0.1"
```

Google has an in-depth writeup of the how/when/why for the chromium resolver behavior here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/dns/README.md

And you can visit `about://net-internals/#dns` for some other tools.

---

I only tested with Chrome and Edge on Windows, and I found that Edge prefers the system dns resolver in my case. I don't think other chromium browsers will, but you may have to adjust based on which browser you're using.